# Why are Python sets not considered sequences?

Tags: set, sequence

In the [python documentation for versions 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) it says explicitly that there are seven sequence data types. The docs go on to discuss sets and tuples some time later (on the same page), both of which are not included in the above seven. Does anyone know what exactly makes defines a sequence type? My intuited definition has sets and tuples fitting the bill quite nicely, and I haven't had any luck finding an explicit official definition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word "[sequence](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+sequence)" implies an order, but sets are not in a specific order.

Comment: You're totally right. And tuples are, in fact, part of the sequence group. Sorry, this is what I get for asking questions at one in the morning.

Comment: Since a `dict` is ordered in Python 3, should it be considered a "sequence"?

Comment: @TósìnAnímáṣahun No. See note about `dict` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14600350/1232660).

Answer (score 0):

Element *index* is a fundamental notion for Python [sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). If you look at the table of sequence operations, you'll see a few that work directly with indices:

```
s[i]        ith item of s, origin 0 (3)
s[i:j]      slice of s from i to j  (3)(4)
s[i:j:k]    slice of s from i to j with step k  (3)(5)
s.index(i)  index of the first occurence of i in s
```

Sets and dictionaries have no notion of an element index, and therefore can't be considered sequences.

Answer (score 0):

> In mathematics, informally speaking, a sequence is an ordered list of objects (or events). Like a set, it contains members (also called elements, or terms). The number of ordered elements (possibly infinite) is called the length of the sequence. Unlike a set, order matters, and exactly the same elements can appear multiple times at different positions in the sequence. Most precisely, a sequence can be defined as a function whose domain is a countable totally ordered set, such as the natural numbers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence

;)

Answer (score 0):

See the [Python glossary](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-sequence):

> Sequence
>
> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a `len()` method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence types are list, str, tuple, and unicode. Note that dict also supports `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, but is considered a mapping rather than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary immutable keys rather than integers.

Tuples are sequences. Sets aren't sequences - they have no order and they can't be indexed via `set[index]` - they even don't have any kind of notion of indices. (They are `iterable`, though - you can iterate over their items.)